# Spring Security Oauth2 only show a login page for non-api requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring boot 1.5.6 and security with OAuth2 and JWT

```
~/repos/jtor > mvn dependency:tree | grep security
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
```

With this configuration below, requests to both `/` and `/api/person` result in a standard OAuth 401:

```
{
"error": "unauthorized",
"error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

What I would like is for requests to `/api/**` to get the 401 while any other requests (like `/` or `/welcome`) to be redirected (302) to my Authorization server (Ping Federate).  After logging in, I would be redirected back and my GET to `/` would return my HTML (or whatever).

In other words, calls made to the API would require a token, while non-api calls would follow the oauth2 code flow.

my config:

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: https://ping-dev.my-comp.com:9031/as/token.oauth2
      userAuthorizationUri: https://ping-dev.my-comp.com:9031/as/authorization.oauth2
      logoutUri: https://ping-dev.my-comp.com:9031/ext/logout
      clientId: oauth2
      clientSecret: foo
      authentication-scheme: header
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          MY KEY HERE
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

my application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class JtorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JtorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
           http
                   .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/info", "/health", "/public/**").permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
           // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    /*
     this class allows me to access public resources with a URL that starts with "public/", which
     allows me to bypass security on any public resource in a clean way.
     */
    @Configuration
    protected static class WebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/");
        }
    }

    /*
    This is the API I want protected via Oauth2/JWT.
    Only calls containing a valid Bearer token should be allowed.
    Calls without a token should get back a standard Oauth 401 error
     */
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    protected static class ApiController {

        @GetMapping("/person")
        public Person getPerson() {
            return Person.builder().id(1).name("Jason").build();
        }

        @Getter
        @Builder
        static class Person {
            private int id;
            private String name;
        }
    }

    /*
    This is the "web app" controller that returns an "app", which will make ajax calls to the api.
    I want this route to be secured, but instead of just returning a 401, I want to start the
    OAuth login process by sending the user to my OAuth Server
     */
    @Controller
    protected static class WebAppController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String webapp() {
            return "index";
        }

        // this should bypass security because it starts with "public"
        @RequestMapping("/public")
        public String publicPage() {
            return "public";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: the inverse strategy would be to use @EnableOAuth2Sso to make all requests require a token (and 302 you otherwise) and follow oauth flow, UNLESS it's an api request (/api/**), in which case just return 401.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle different parts of your application with different authentication mechanisms, you can just create additional configuration class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and specify your security constraints there.

Make sure that you specify the URLs, to which your security config should be applied, in an AntMatcher before calling `.authorizeRequests()`. See code below.

You can set the order of your security configurations using `@Order` annotation.

**Example with HTTP basic authentication**

```
@Configuration
@Order(2) //will be applied after @Order(1), etc...
protected AnotherSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
            .antMatcher("/api/**") //apply only to api endpoints
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .httpBasic(); //set to basic auth
    }
}
```

Comment: that won't really help me.  I am getting the correct security applied.  I want better control handling the exception.  If the resource you request starts with "/api/**", then don't bother 302'ing the user to the authorization server.

Comment: so if you setup e.g. one security configuration to "/api/**" with `@EnableResourceServer` as you have it and then one configuration to "/**" with lower priority with OAuth2 code flow settings, it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
....
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint())
....
    }

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint() {
        return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
            @Override
            public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                //your code here - can key off of the request
            }
        };
    }
```